# sed leaves only first letter

Tags: regex, sed

I want to remove most of rows in log in that case it's windows eventlog.

I tested it on EventCode=4624 - successful login

```
02/01/2018 09:56:03 AM
LogName=Security
SourceName=Microsoft Windows security auditing.
EventCode=4624
EventType=0
Type=Information
ComputerName=COMPUTER1
TaskCategory=Logon
OpCode=Info
RecordNumber=1072237543
Keywords=Audit Success ...
```

I tried to use sed like below:

```
sed "s/(?!Type\=\w+).+//g"
```

but that got me only one letter "T" as below:

```
T
```

What I am doing wrong?

Expected output:

```
Type=Information
```

Comment: Are you after `sed "/Type=[[:alnum:]_]/!d"`? What is the expected output?

Comment: What kind of rows do you want to remove?

Comment: Your question is quite obscure. Please add a little more detail

Comment: @akuzma, please always do add expected output into your post in code tags to avoid confusions.

Comment: "windows eventlog". If that is really an MS Windows file, then you need to change the `\r\n` line endings to just `\n`. Use `dos2unix file` (but don't expect that log file to work in Windows afterwards, work on a copy?). Good luck.

Comment: Sed doesn't know about look-arounds, it only knows Basic and Extended Regular Expressions.

Comment: If my answer is not what you mean please add a comment and update the question.

Answer (score 2):

You may use

```
sed -E "/^Type=[[:alnum:]_]+$/!d"
```

It will remove all lines that do no match

- `^` - start of line
- `Type=` - literal string
- `[[:alnum:]_]+` - 1 or more alphanumeric or `_` chars
- `$` - end of line.

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/N8yGzj).